# Как cымитировать ввод значения в поле, используя консоль браузера?

Tags: javascript

Отсутствует возможность использовать стороннее ПО, но присутствует куча полей которые нужно проверять.

Имеется поле которое принимает положительные чиcла, при вводе отрицательного, выделяется красным и выводит текст ошибки. При вводе отрицательного значения командой `$element.value=-1`, в поле появляется значение, но поле никак на него не реагирует. Имеется ли другой способ сымитировать ввод так, чтобы получить ожидаемый результат?

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById('test').value = -1;
document.getElementById('test').dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

```html
<input id="test" oninput="console.log(this.value)" />
```

```js
document.getElementById('test').value = -1;
document.getElementById('test').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

```html
<input id="test" onchange="console.log(this.value)" />
```

Comment: Не получается, правильно я понимаю, что в document.getElementById('test').dispatchEvent(new Event('input')); мне нужно использовать событие, которое присвоено моему полю?

Comment: @user411107 da.

Comment: Поле имеет три события change, keyup, keydown, можно пример как это должно выглядеть?

Comment: @user411107 `$element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))`

Comment: неа, так не работает, пробовал :(

Comment: @user411107 А-а-а, все понятно.

Comment: Есть еще идеи?) После change валидации поля не происходит

Comment: @user411107 Какие, черт возьми, идеи? Я должен вообразить Ваш код?

Comment: Я думал "А-а-а, все понятно" это значит есть решение

Comment: @user411107 Нет. Это означало сарказм.

Comment: А-а-а, все понятно